# suggestion: `end-user` tag

Tags: discussion

How about an `end-user` tag?

I see it being used for questions coming from the perspective of those not involved administering or developing sharepoint, just regular users utilizing out of the box features.

Answer (score 3):

It certainly sounds like a good idea, but tags aren't purposefully added by the moderation team: You can create them yourself at 300+ reputation simply by adding a post with that tag.

With that in mind, if it hasn't popped into existence of its own accord by now, then it isn't likely that it's needed.

Comment: To play devil's advocate.. we do have a [tag:development] tag. Either way you are right Stuart, if someone feels so inclined, they can go ahead and create the tag.

Comment: We developers obviously like to blow our own trumpets more. :)